# Netbeans JavaDB won't start

Tags: netbeans, derby, javadb, netbeans-12

Similarly to https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=257948 , my JavaDB connections starting going haywire a couple days ago.

They were working nicely with Netbeans 12.1 and Glassfish 5.1 and JDK 15 until two days ago. I use the embedded driver in my codebase, and I use Services -> JavaDB to inspect my tables from within the Netbeans IDE.

Two days ago, without having changed anything on my system or in my setup, Services -> JavaDB stopped connecting to the database. JavaDB simply won't start. Until two days ago, I would get a prompt asking for username and password (which were empty). Now, I just get [this in the output window](https://pastebin.com/2sRPRhNg), with an eternal spinner saying "JavaDB starting".

I have tried uninstalling all JDKs and JREs, uninstalling Netbeans, and reinstalling again with:

- JDK 15
- Netbeans 12.1
- Glassfish 5.1

But this didn't fix the issue, see screenshot. I get an eternal "Starting the Java DB server" or "Connecting to database" spinner, but no username prompt and no connection to the database : [image: Netbeans JavaDB connection error]

I also tried starting from the command line as per the [instructions given here](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=257948#c7). I don't see any errors when doing that:

```
C:\Users\johnrdorazio>java -cp "C:\Users\johnrdorazio\GlassFish_Server\javadb\lib\derby.jar;C:\Users\johnrdorazio\GlassFish_Server\javadb\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\Users\johnrdorazio\GlassFish_Server\javadb\lib\derbynet.jar" -Dderby.system.home="C:\Users\johnrdorazio\AppData\Roaming\BibleGetOpenOfficePlugin" org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start
Thu Oct 22 22:16:27 CEST 2020 : Gestore della sicurezza installato con i criteri di sicurezza di base del server.
Thu Oct 22 22:16:29 CEST 2020 : Server di rete Apache Derby: 10.14.2.0 - (1828579) avviato e pronto ad accettare connessioni sulla porta 1527
```

I have verified paths are all correct in Java DB Properties. I'm at a loss as where to go from here.

I have set the System variable `JAVA_HOME` to the JDK 15 path, and the System Path contains only the `JAVA_HOME` variable (as regards Java paths).

Comment: With JDK 9+, you need to use Derby 15+; with JDK 8, you need to use Derby 14. I'm not sure if that is your particular problem or not. A more detailed breakdown is here: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the problem, I have also tried downloading Apache Derby 15.2 directly from Apache (https://downloads.apache.org/db/derby/db-derby-10.15.2.0/) and pointing the JavaDB properties to this folder, but to no avail, same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was just a guess. Perhaps you can edit your question to include more detailed information (log files, error messages, stack traces from exceptions, etc.) Try to avoid screen shots and images, they hide a lot of detail and are hard to read.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can provide? I not only provided the screenshot, I also provided the content of the output window in a pastebin link. I am not seeing any exceptions, this problem is not occurring within my code it's occurring within the Netbeans interface under the Services area.
I guess my best bet is the [ticket on the Netbeans JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4933)...

Answer (score 0):

I my case the problem was that JavaDB Properties had the default Java DB Installtion location:

C:\Program Files\glassfish web-5.1.0\glassfish5\javadb.

Whereas in NetBeans 12.0, the actual path to glassfish, in my case is:

C:\Program Files\eclipse-glassfish web-5.1.0\glassfish5\javadb

I corrected that by using the actual path and then JavaDB connected immediately.